# Send requests to a website from an iOS app

Tags: ios

I was wondering if there's a way to send requests to a website, directly from an iOS app, for example, I type my username and password in two inputbox and then I just tap a "login" button on the iPhone, sending the credentials to a website. Can it be done?

Comment: No, this is technically impossible given current smartphone technology. Maybe in iOS 10 and Android 6...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send requests to a website from an iOS application. You're probably looking to perform a HTTP action.

There is a great guide by the Spring development team which guides you through the process of using RESTful services on iOS, this includes Posting data to a web service.

RESTful services also allow you the create, retrieve, update and delete data from a webservice too using a variety of HTTP calls.